# Can't arrange my elements nicely with borderlayout

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, border-layout

I try to order my elements with Borderlayout since Gridlayout makes everything the same size.

What I see is this:
[image: what i see]
while manually resizing it, I can have the following
[image: what I want to see]

Here's part of my code

```
public InputPanel() {

    tfield = new TextField("Search your terms here!");
    add(tfield, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

    searchButton = new JButton("Search");
    searchButton.addActionListener(this);
    add(searchButton, BorderLayout.LINE_START);

    clearButton = new JButton("Clear Text");
    clearButton.addActionListener(this);
    add(clearButton, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

    resultsArea = new TextArea();
    add(resultsArea, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
}
```

It seems like it does not help in arranging. It's just like I have used FlowLayout.

How can I format it properly?

Comment: Since you are using Eclipse, why don't you use WindowBuilder?

Comment: So how do you want the layout? Do you want it as the second picture shows?

Comment: @Devolus Nobody serious should use a GUI builder, except maybe to throw together an outline of the layout. The resulting code is a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: The resulting code can be maintained by the GUIBuilder anyaway. Also the code from WindowBuilder looks not so bad. Only the constraints for GridBag are complicated, but they are so also without a builder. :)

Comment: @JohnSnow Yes, somehow like the second one.

Comment: @Devolus Will try it next time, but for now i would like to make it happend that way.

Comment: @Devolus Using a GUIBuilder without understanding the fundamentals behind is a very good way to make poor, ugly and unmanageable UI's. It is therefore a very good practice to learn Swing outside GUI-builder's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For BorderLayout you should be using NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST and CENTER to place your components. To achive the above layout, you should create one panel that has FLOWLAYOUT, where you add the textfield, seachbutton and clear button. This panel will then be placed inside BorderLayout.NORTH. After this you place the JTextArea inside BorderLayout.NORTH

```
public InputPanel() {

    JPanel topPanel = new JPanel(); // Create a new panel
    topPanel.setLayout(FlowLayout()); //Left to right alignment is default for FlowLayout

    //Add your textfield and buttons to the panel with flowlayout
    tfield = new TextField("Search your terms here!");  
    topPanel.add(tfield);

    searchButton = new JButton("Search");
    searchButton.addActionListener(this);
    topPanel.add(searchButton);

    clearButton = new JButton("Clear Text");
    clearButton.addActionListener(this);
    topPanel.add(clearButton);

    add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH); // Add the panel containing the buttons and textfield in the north

    resultsArea = new TextArea();
    add(resultsArea, BorderLayout.CENTER); //Add the textarea in the Center

}
```

This gives me the below appearance:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your try, but strangely the apprearence wont change for me.                                   (topPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout()); by the way)

Comment: So you got it to work? Great, would be weird otherwise since it gives me the desired look :)

Comment: Yes, i created another panel for some other elements and arranged them perfectly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Seems you have missed `GridBagLayout`, which is the number one choice for a truly flexible layout manager. With `BorderLayout` you can also achieve a lot, but only with many levels of nesting, and the code to build it is quite unmanageable.

Comment: Nested layouts can be managed by putting each panel in it's own class.  GridBagLayout is the choice for laying out a form, but some layouts have to be nested.